# android TabLayout how to show shadow top

Tags: android

android TabLayout how to show shadow top 
im using tablayout is bottom how to make shadow as like this

please help me ?  shadow show top

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".GlobalHub.GlobalActivity">


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/tablayout" />


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    singleLine="true"


    android:id="@id/tablayout"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/black"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"

    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/jetColor"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_46sdp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

android:background="@drawable/shadow_tablayout"

    />
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the shadow, use `android:elevation` attribute on the `TabLayout` in your `xml` file :

```
android:elevation="10dp"
```

read more about using `elevation` and defining shadows in `Android` [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html)

If you just want the top shadow then try these 2 solutions :

**OR**

Wrap the `Tablayout` in a `LinearLayout` and set the background of `LinearLayout` as the `9patch` image with top shadow.

**OR**

Put an ImageView above your `TabLayout` and set its `src` to be a vertical `GradientDrawable` defined in XML, as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html?hl=en#Shape)

Comment: you just need the top shadow?

Comment: Yes please help me

Comment: do you know about 9patch? you should use a 9patch image as the background if you just want the top shadow. here's a nice tutorial on how to use 9patch in android : http://sapandiwakar.in/adding-shadows-to-views-in-android-using-9-patch-image/

Comment: but my case tablayout

Comment: you can wrap the Tablayout in a LinearLayout and set the background of LinearLayout as the 9patch image with top shadow.

Comment: or you can put an `ImageView` above your `TabLayout` and set its `src` to be a vertical `GradientDrawable` defined in `XML`, as explained here : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html?hl=en#Shape

Comment: 7 th 
 
or you can put an ImageView above your